# Segfault in simple hash table

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, hashtable

I am trying to write a simple hash table in C and  I am getting a very strange segfault when testing it with the code shown my `main()`.

**The Design:** I have a hash table with an underlying array of size 10,000. I hold a double pointer to the start of an array of `struct node_t` (or `node`) pointers. When I want to `put()` something into the hash table, I check if the `node` element at the appropriate location is `NULL`. If it is, I create a new node to fill the spot, otherwise, if there are collisions, I build a linked list off of the colliding node.

**The Scenario:** In `main()`, I am trying to `put()` the number 3328 into the hash table. Instead, the program segfaults. This makes no sense to me as the previous `put()` works fine and you can clearly see that I set all the initial pointers to NULL. As far as I know, the pointer that refers to hash table location 3328 is not getting set to NULL because when I dereference it in the `put()` function, that's when it segfaults. My main function looks like it should set all the pointers to NULL just fine though...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int TABLE_SIZE = 10000;

typedef struct node_t {
    int key;
    int value;
    struct node_t* next;
} node;

node** table;

inline node** get_node_address(int key) {
    key = (key > -key ? key : -key) % TABLE_SIZE;
    return (node**) (table + key * sizeof(node*)); 
}

inline node* new_node(int key, int value) {
    node* n = malloc(sizeof(node));
    n->key = key;
    n->value = value;
    n->next = NULL;
    return n;
}

void put(int key, int value) {
    node** n = (node**) get_node_address(key);
    node* iterator = (node*) *n;

    if (*n == NULL) {
        *n = new_node(key, value);
    } else {
        while (iterator->next != NULL)
            iterator = iterator->next;

        iterator->next = new_node(key, value);
    }
}

int* get(int key) {
    node* iterator = (node*) *get_node_address(key);

    while (iterator != NULL && iterator->key != key) {
        iterator = iterator->next;
    }

    if (iterator == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else
        return &(iterator->value); 
}

int main() {
    printf("Starting..\n");

    int i;
    table = malloc(sizeof(node*) * TABLE_SIZE);
    memset(table, 0, sizeof(node*) * TABLE_SIZE);

    for (i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++) {
        table[i] = NULL;
        printf("setting %x\n", &table[i]);
    }

    printf("before bad: %x\n", *get_node_address(3327));
    printf("bad address: %x\n", *get_node_address(3328));
    printf("last address: %x\n", table + sizeof(node*) * TABLE_SIZE);

    printf("Hashing...\n");

    put(3328, 3338);
    printf("%d", *get(3328));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use a debugger to debug your program?

Comment: What's wrong with `key >= 0 ? key : -key` ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's at least one problem:

```
inline node** get_node_address(int key) {
      key = (key > -key ? key : -key) % TABLE_SIZE;
      return (node**) (table + key * sizeof(node*)); /* <---- */
}
```

You mustn't multiply `key`. Because of the way pointer arithmetic works in C, `table + key` yields the `key`-th element.

Comment: Wow I would have never figured that out. I changed that and it works flawlessly! So in pointer arithmetic, if one of the values isn't a pointer itself, C will multiply by the size of a pointer for me?

Comment: @Daniel In pointer arithmetic it will multiply by the size of the pointed type.

Comment: The syntax `return &table[key];`  is less error prone, and probably more readable.

Answer (score 0):

The above code can be simplified a lot:

```
void put(int key, int value) {
  node **n = get_node_address(key);


  for (n = get_node_address(key); *n; n = &(*n)->next) {;}

  if(*n == NULL)
    *n = new_node(key, value);

}

int* get(int key) {
  node  **n;

  for (n = get_node_address(key); *n; n = &(*n)->next) {
    if (n->key == key) break;
    }

  if(*n == NULL)
    return NULL;
  else
    return &(*n)->value; 
}
```